# DartPad cannot import 'dart:js'?

Tags: dart, firebase

What's wrong with that code https://dartpad.dartlang.org/59c9ac878a0335fdcffb or with DartPad?
It produces

> Uncaught TypeError: constr is not a function

in the CONSOLE.

Comment: Works fine for me. Can you please add a screenshot of the error?

Comment: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/59c9ac878a0335fdcffb don't work https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_AWqJRf16SGSjNPeGhhVkpUZmM/view

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-pad/issues/690

Yes, part of dart:js is implemented in javascript files, which we're not able to load. You can see error messages to this effect in the devtools console.

You could try hosting those javascript files on a CDN, and referencing them from your html file - that might work.